# Magento why 3 tax calculation methods?

Tags: algorithm, magento

Today I was studying how Magento tax calculation works to understand the difference between the behaviors for "**Tax Calculation Method Based On**".

I traced deep into **Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Tax** which implements all methods in the **_unitBaseCalculation**, **_rowBaseCalculation**, **_totalBaseCalculation**.

I discovered that they produce exactly the same results. So why did they go through the trouble of implementing them ?

For example, unit-price calculation goes to the trouble of calculating the tax for the single unit and then dividing the discount amount by the qty (if tax applied after discount), then subtracting both, and then multiplying again by the quantity... which just introduces rounding errors.

Whereas Row Total calculation is the most intuitive one (which takes the price from the row "subtotal") minus discount amount (if tax applied after discount).

While the third one is just an aggregation of the second, calculated at once.

This just introduces confusion and obfuscation to the tax calculation logic. Can anyone shed a light onto why this was done ?

(Rounding errors ? Backward compatibility ? Candidate for TheDailyWTF prize ?)

**EDIT**: For the record this is true as of Magento 1.6 and 1.7, don't know about older versions.

Comment: "which just introduces rounding errors" - are you sure? Can you *prove* that both methods always produce the same result? Example of possible problem: If tax on an item has to be an exact number of {currency unit}, with a tax rate of 17%, 100 items costing 20 each will have a *different* total tax than 1 item costing 2000!

Comment: Hmmm.. I was mainly testing with "nice" numbers, so they were giving the same result in my tests. I mean by "rounding errors" that each method will give a different result depending on when it is rounding, which seems counter intuitive to me.

Comment: Accountants (and even more so tax inspectors) are strange folk who are rarely impressed by intuition, simple mathematics, or indeed common sense. People have been doing billing and tax for a lot longer than they've been doing programming; there's a *lot* of rules and regulations 'prior art' that software has to follow, even if it seems obvious with hindsight that a rewrite would give a much better system. It's still reasonable to ask though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this from: https://gist.github.com/2572772 (by Alan Storm it seems)

> This feature was probably motivated by individual local rules (or client requests) as to  how taxes should be calculated, as fractional amounts could add up differently depending on when adding and rounding occurs. THat said, I haven't run through the code to see if my guesses are right so YMMV. Other areas to consider for future research.
>
> How does each mode play with shopping cart price rules and store wide discounts

For shopping cart price rules, it goes through painstaking trouble to divide the discount amount (which may not be divisible by the quote item quantity thus introducing a rounding error) so that the end result is the actually the same process, but only with different "when"s and "where"s as to rounding.